# Do i exclude data used in a training set to run predict () model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, training-data

I have a question about running predict on data used for training set.

I took a portion of my initial dataset and split that portion into 80% (train) and 20% (test). I trained the model on 80% of training set

```
model <- train(name ~ ., data = train.df, method = ...)
```

and then run the model on 20% test data:

```
predict(model, newdata = test.df, type = "prob")
```

Now I want to predict using my trained model on initial dataset which also includes the training portion. Do I need to exclude that portion that was used for the training?

Comment: This is really more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com, but you'll need to be more clear on what it is that you're trying to do. It looks like you are doing things correctly, in that you are evaluating your model on data that it was not trained on. If you predict on the initial dataset excluding the training dataset, aren't you just left with `test.df`? What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: @Tchotchke I had initial dataset, and took portion of it, which is  around 10%. Then I split this 10% data into training and test sets. But I still have the rest 90% of the initial data that was not used in neither training nor test. Right now I am trying to predict on my whole dataset, but it  includes that 10% of data used in training and testing. So I am not sure if this 10% data should be excluded.

Comment: That's much clearer now, but what is your ultimate objective? Are you assessing model performance?

Answer (score 0):

When you report accuracy to a third person about how good your machine learning model works, you always report the accuracy you get on the data set that was not used in training (and validation).

You can report your accuracy numbers for the over all data set but always include the remark that this data set also includes the data partition that was used for training the machine learning algorithm.

This care is taken to make sure your algorithm has not overfitted on your training set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

Answer (score 0):

Julie, I saw your comment below your original post.  I would suggest you edit the original post and include your data split to be more complete in your question.  It would also help to know what method of regression/classification you're using.

I'm assuming you're trying to assess the accuracy of your model with the 90% of data you left out.  Depending on the number of samples you used in your training set you may or may not have the accuracy you'd like.  Accuracy will also depend on your approach to the method of regression/classification you used.

To answer your question directly: you don't need to exclude anything from your dataset - the model doesn't change when you call predict().

All you're doing when you call predict is filling in the x-variables in your model with whatever data you supply.  Your model was fitted to your training set, so if you supply training set data again it will still create predictions.  Note though, for proving accuracy your results will be skewed if you include the set of data that you fit the model to since that's what it learned from to create predictions in the first place - kind of like watching a game, and then watching the same game again and being asked to make predictions about it.